# phpExcel , how to write superscript in an excel

Tags: php, phpexcel, superscript

I`m using  the PHPExcel class ,to write in an excel file.

My question is: how to write a data in a cell with superscript,if my value is `( M<sup>3</sup>)` to M<sup>3</sup> (in excel)

```
  // $data['dataLashing'][$i]['units_name'] - it`s a value from db in LOOP

$getExcelObject
            ->mergeCells("A$startRow:E$startRow")->setCellValue("A$startRow",$data['dataLashing'][$i]['material'])
            ->mergeCells("F$startRow:G$startRow")->setCellValue("F$startRow",$data['dataLashing'][$i]['units_name'])
            ->mergeCells("H$startRow:I$startRow")->setCellValue("H$startRow",$data['dataLashing'][$i]['quantity']);
```

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this one:**

```
      $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
      $objRichText->createText($data['dataLashing'][$i]['units_name']);

   //condition your html tag
      if(preg_match('/<sup>(.+)<\/sup>/i', $data['dataLashing'][$i]['units_name'],$result)) {
         $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
         $objCubed = $objRichText->createText(preg_replace('/<sup>(.+)<\/sup>/i', '', $data['dataLashing'][$i]['units_name']));
         $objCubed = $objRichText->createTextRun($result[1]);
         $objCubed->getFont()->setSuperScript(true);
      }      
      $getExcelObject
       ->mergeCells("A$startRow:E$startRow")->setCellValue("A$startRow",$data['dataLashing'][$i]['material'])
        ->mergeCells("F$startRow:G$startRow")->setCellValue("F$startRow",$objRichText)
        ->mergeCells("H$startRow:I$startRow")->setCellValue("H$startRow",$data['dataLashing'][$i]['quantity']);

     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to populate the cell with rich text:

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$objRichText->createText('M');

$objCubed = $objRichText->createTextRun('3');
$objCubed->getFont()->setSuperScript(true);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A18')->setValue($objRichText);
```

Comment: yes it`s working,but in the database , my values are contents a html tags like this M<sup>3</sup>.. I want to do it dynamically

Comment: There is no method available in PHPExcel to convert HTML markup to rich text runs, so this is something you'd need to write yourself

Comment: @Dezigo Is that the only possible HTML tag that will exist in the string? Where is the text coming from (i.e. before it gets entered into the database). Give us a complete list of all the tags we need to parse (before someone suggests using a Regex and is immediately hanged for it). Oh, and +1 this answer.

Comment: Yes. Only a one html tag <sup</sup>. Do you think I need to use a regex?